# region - date & time question

Tags: c#, winforms

in my C# program i receive date & time like this: `DateTime.Now`

and i get: `19/09/2010 20:10:30` because my region is: `Hebrew (Israel)`

but What happens if I'll install my program on computer with region `English (united states)`

I'll probably get an error because the format is `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

my question is, How to ensure that i Always get the date in `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format ?

in any type of region ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Output just generated:

> 19/09/2010 19:31:20

Just so you know "HH" is 24 hour clock hours, so from 0-23 and "hh" is 12 hour clock hours, so from 1-12. So with "hh" you'd need a "tt" after it. You also generally don't have the "0" in front of any hours < 10 when using a 12 hour clock.

Like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:sstt");
```

> 19/09/2010 7:34:25PM

All of the format specifiers (so "h", "mm", "MM", etc) can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx